# hg pull over ssh has suddenly started giving no suitable response from remote hg

Tags: mercurial, ssh

My team has been using mercurial for a while. We use ssh to connect to a central remote repository. Haven't had any issues with pushing or pulling over ssh to remote repos... until today!

Everyone else is on the LAN, i work remotely and connect to the LAN with vpn (cisco). No one else is having problems now, but suddenly, no matter what I try, I get "no suitable response from remote hg!"

I am able to access everything else on the LAN, and I can even ssh (in a terminal) into the remote server holding the remote repositories.

Here is the output using the debug command

```
sending hello command
sending between command
no suitable response from remote hg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, turns out my rsa key mysteriously disappeared from the list in PageAnt, and once I added it back in, everything works properly. strange, but resolved